# I can not access dictionary in my python code

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I have written a function that takes code from a sites script element, strips characters, adds double quotes to keys using string replace, and whats returned was what I thought was a dictionary. yet I can't pull values from it. I tried to access values by doing

```
results['file']
```

and that didn't work. I was given an error message saying something like

```
it expected a number and instead got a string.
```

I then tried

```
results[0]
```

and all that was returned was

```
{
```

I also tried

```
results.file
```

and that didn't work. So while googling and researching python books I saw a values function being used on a dictionary like this

```
dict.values()
```

but when I tried it I got

```
'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Heres my code for my function

```
def panties():
        pan_url = 'http://www.panvideos.com'
        html = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})

        def youtube_link(url):
            youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
            video_row = soupdata.find('div', {'class': 'video-player'})
            entries = [{'text': str(div),
                        } for div in video_row][3]['text']

            oldstring = str(entries)
            removed = '<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer("video-setup").setup('
            newstring = oldstring.replace(removed, "")
            removed_two = ');</script>'
            newstring_two = newstring.replace(removed_two, "")


            #Allows for multiple string replacement
            rdict = {
                'file': '"file"',
                'image': '"image"',
                'primary': '"primary"',
                'stretching': '"stretching"',
                'width': '"width"',
                'aspectratio': '"aspectratio"',
                'autostart': '"autostart"',
                'logo': '"logo"',
                'position': '"position"',
                # 'link': '"link"',
                'sharing': '"sharing"',
            }

            robj = re.compile('|'.join(rdict.keys()))
            result = robj.sub(lambda m: rdict[m.group(0)], newstring_two)
            parsed_json = json.loads(json.dumps(result))

            soc = parsed_json.replace('link', ' "link" ', 2)

            return soc
```

and here is what it returns

```
{"file":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slCSLeZueI4",
  "image":"http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/slCSLeZueI4/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "primary":"html5",
  "stretching":"fill",
  "controlbar":"bottom",
  "width":"100%",
  "aspectratio":"16:9",
  "autostart":"true",
  "logo":{
      "file":"http://www.panvideos.com/uploads/bien-png578aab16676e1.png",
      "position":"bottom-right", 
      "link" :"http://www.panvideos.com/"},
      "sharing":{ 
          "link" :"http://www.panvideos.com/video/3178/la-nina-y-el-lobo-video-oficial/","sites":
       ["facebook","twitter","linkedin","pinterest","tumblr","googleplus","reddit"]}}
```

I tested it in a json validator, it has double quotes like json is supposed to, it's enclosed in curly brackets. What's the correct syntax to make this work. also this is in a django app. I put that just to be complete and just in case this makes a difference

EDIT:
my views.py

```
        pan = panties()
        context = {
            'pan': pan,
        }
```

and in my template

```
    {% for p in pan %}
        Title: {{p.text}}<br>
        Href: {{p.href}}<br>
        Tube: {{p.tube}}<hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: show the code that calls this function? Are you sure you put return value in results?

Comment: There are some things you can do to narrow this down - your `<dictionary>[<key>]' is right - and your error message suggests that what you think is a dictionary is actually a string ,...

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 thanks for the response. If I try to use json.loads I get this error message "Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 436 (char 435)"

Comment: that messages says to me that your json is broken in some way. Certainly whatever `results` is - it isn't a dictionary - and the error message tells you it is a string.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 but when I put it in the json validator it's fine

Comment: Well - all I can go on is the error messages - whatever you might think `results` is - Python has created a string - that is a massive clue as to where the problem is. If you look at your code `results` is a string - you create it by calling `re.sub` and the return from `re.sub` is a string. in your code it is either `parsed_json` or `soc` which is the dictionary, assuming your json is valid.

Comment: didn't you ask this question in three different ways already?

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

tells you that "results" is a string. You can use [python-json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to decode the string to a python object:

```
somevariable = json.loads(results)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I just tried it and got the following error message "Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 436 (char 435)"

Comment: So on line 1 of your json string - at column 436 (or close to there), you are missing a ',' - the message is very clear.

Comment: Where line 436 and 435 is doesnt make sense.